# Remove a DomNode with a certain class in PHP

Tags: php, dom

I have a HTML document (string) which contains a div with the class "foo":

```
<html>
<head>
  ...
</head>
<body>
<div class="whatever">Blabla</div>
<div>
   <span>Text</span>
</div>
<table>
   <tr><td><div class="foo">GARBAGE</div></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
```

I only would like to remove all divs with class of "foo" and this is what I have so far:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($myhtml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$all = $xpath->query("/html");

$result = remove_elements_with_class('foo', $all);
```

How does the `remove_elements_with_class` function look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After:

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
```

You need to:

1. Select all the nodes that you want to remove
2. Call [`DOMNode::removeChild()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php) on those nodes

So, to accomplish the first task, you can issue an XPath query that finds all of the `<div>` nodes whose class is `foo`. That query would look like:

```
//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' foo ')]
```

Note that this handles the cases where an element can have more than one class, i.e. `foo bar baz` and `baz foo bar`. If this is undesirable, and you only want to match the class exactly (so now only a class with exactly `foo` will match), the query becomes:

```
//div[@class = 'foo']
```

And, in PHP, this becomes:

```
$nodes = $xpath->query( "//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' foo ')]");
```

From here, you have all the nodes you want to remove in `$nodes`, so just iterate over them, and remove them from the document by grabbing the `<div>`'s parent node, and removing its child node:

```
foreach( $nodes as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild( $node);
}
```

That's all it takes! You can see it working in [this demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/wLtpct).

**Edit:** To keep the `<div>` and just remove the contents, set the node's `nodeValue` attribute to an empty string:

```
foreach( $nodes as $node) {
    $node->nodeValue = '';
}
```

You can see it working in [this updated demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/cS1l1B). You could also replace the `<div>` with a newly created `<div>`, as that approach seems more bulletproof, but this should work for your use-case.

Comment: Wow, thanks this actually works!. Is there a way that I only can remove "GARBAGE" and keep the div there? So it's an empty div with class "foo". Thats actually what I need, sorry